# Inherit class inside a module of helper file in another helper file Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, model-view-controller, helper

i have a controller inside payment folder named **gateway_controller.rb**

```
class Payment::GatewayController < PaymentController
  include Payment::GatewayHelper::Handler

  def set_handler
    @handler = StandardGatewayInterface.get_handler("test") 
  end
end
```

And i have their helper files in **helpers/payment/gateway_helper/handler.rb**
which looks like

```
module Payment::GatewayHelper::Handler
  class StandardGatewayInterface

    def self.get_handler(payment_method)
      puts self.descendants
    end

    # Get a list of subclasses.
    def self.descendants
      ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |cls| cls < self }
    end
  end
end
```

and there is another file in **/helpers/payment/test_fort.rb** where there is a class that inherits from `StandardGatewayInterface`.

```
require_relative './gateway_helper/handler'
class TestFort < StandardGatewayInterface
  include Payment::GatewayHelper::Handler
  def build_redirect_url(user_id, product, success_url)
    puts "===in==="
  end

end
```

when i call `StandardGatewayInterface.get_handler("test")` it gets inside the helper method, where i call `self.descendants` which has to return `TestFort` since it inherits from `StandardGatewayInterface`.But what iam getting is an empty array.

How will i make this work?

Comment: Tried. Still the same error.

Comment: It might be that `class` is still not loaded in the memory, and thus `ObjectSpace` does not see it

Comment: Tried requiring **/helpers/payment/test_fort.rb** inside **helpers/payment/gateway_helper/handler.rb**. In that case **[TestFort]** gets returned. But still cannot access its methods.And reloading the page again return empty array.

Comment: `# Get a list of subclasses.` -- This is a strange thing to do. A class should not typically know/care about what inherits from it. Could you redesign the code to not do this?

Comment: If not, then maybe try a solution that doesn't require mysterious behaviour in `ObjectSpace`. You can define the `inherited` method in `StandardgatewayInterface`: `def self.inherited(klass); @descendants ||= []; @descendants << klass; end`